# Rails 3: Why the field with error is not wrapped with "field_with_errors" div when validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, field-with-errors

My `Product` class has `price` field, which has an appropriate column in `Products` table in the database, and `new_shop` helper field (which is defined as `attr_accessor`, and does not has an appropriate column in `Products` table in the database).

When validation on `price` fails, the input field is wrapped with `field_with_errors` div, but when the validation on `new_shop` fails, it is not wrapped with `field_with_errors` div. Why ?

Here is the generated HTML for these input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="product[price]" id="product_price">
<input type="text" value="" name="product[new_shop]" id="product_new_shop">
```

---

Some more info:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :new_shop 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop
  validates_presence_of :price
  ...
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  ...
end
```

When the form is submitted, the `new_shop` value is passed to product's `shop_attributes[:name]`.

Comment: Please include the validation code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's the :name attribute that actually fails validation?  That is why new_shop doesn't get the fieldWithErrors div then: this looks at @product.errors to decide on a field by field basis whether it has errors.  ie

```
#comes to do the :new_shop field
#looks to see if @product.errors.on(:new_shop) is not blank
#if it isn't blank, wraps the error div round it.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One little question: what does the `on` method do ? I didn't find a documentation on it. Could you refer me please ?